# HAProxy - URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

Requesting help to rewrite the following url.

/test/%2012341234 to /test/12341234. I tried the following. But it din't work.

reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /test/%2012341234(.*)    \1\ /test/12341234\2

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without the whole context, it's hard to answer you.
Furthermore, HAProxy version, and whole anonymized configuration is welcome too!

That said, in your particular example, this should do the trick:
 reqirep ^([^\ ]\ /test/)%20(12341234.*) \1\2

note that reqirep won't work in tunnel mode.
So you must have at least option http-server-close, httpclose or forceclose in your configuration.

Baptiste